# Searching in table by regex not showing proper output

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

this is my code for searching  . there is some issue with regex when i search full text its working fine but i search middle char its not working .

for example if i search "apple" or "ap" its work but if i with search   "pl" its not working. below is my code sorry for bad English.

```
var $rows = $('#dvtable tr');

$('#box').keyup(function() {

                    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
                        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
                        text;

                    $rows.show().filter(function() {
                        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
                        return !reg.test(text);
                    }).hide();
                });
```

Comment: It won't match the middle, you're using `^`, `$` anchors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching a word starting this.val() `'^(?=.*\b' + $.trim($(this).val()))`

If you want that regex match with inner substrings you need to specify that may be some letters before your literal

```
'^(?=.*\\b\\w*' + $.trim($(this).val()))
```

Ex:

```
var literal = 'ap'
var val = '^(?=.*\\b\\w*' + $.trim(literal).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$', reg = RegExp(val, 'i')
reg.test("apple")
>>>>true
var literal = "pl"
var val = '^(?=.*\\b\\w*' + $.trim(literal).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$', reg = RegExp(val, 'i')
reg.test("apple")
>>>>true
var literal = 'x'
var val = '^(?=.*\\b\\w*' + $.trim(literal).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$', reg = RegExp(val, 'i')
reg.test("apple")
>>>>false
```